# assigning values to matlab structure fieldnames containing spaces

Tags: matlab

I am working with a large predefined Matlab struct that has several fieldnames containing spaces and strange characters, like:

```
Pending Equity > T: [20000x1 double]
```

I can see the data fine:

```
>> r.('Pending Equity > T')(1)

ans =

     0
```

However, I cannot assign a new value:

```
>> r.('Pending Equity > T')(1) = 5
??? Invalid field name: 'Pending Equity > T'.
```

Any ideas?  I am unable to change the original fieldnames.

Comment: I don't think you're working with a struct, but rather an object. Can you run `class(r)` and post the output?

Comment: Sadly, it is indeed a struct:>> class(r)

    ans =

    struct

Answer (score 1):

From [struct documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/struct.html#inputarg_field):

> Field name, specified as a string. Valid field names begin with a letter, and can contain letters, digits, and underscores. The maximum length of a field name is the value that the namelengthmax function returns.

so no spaces (nor `><!:;,`etc), try using underscores instead of the spaces.

If you're sure you can read out the data just fine, then how was it constructed in the first place? As you can see from the above, such data structure are not supported.

Comment: Not positive.  It is a response to a query to a MS SQL Server db.  These are ancient legacy systems I'm dealing with.

Comment: can't you rename the names before the conversion thing puts in in a matlab struct?

Comment: Nah, I'm really unable to edit the conversion thing--the methods I must use to query the db, etc., are all prebuilt and it would be difficult to make changes.  The hassles of working at a big company...

Answer (score 1):

Well you could make a new `struct`, which is a copy of `r` but with valid fieldnames:

```
names    = fieldnames(r);
newnames = genvarname(names);

for ii = 1:numel(names)
    new_r.(newnames{ii}) = r.(names{ii});
end
```

This will allow you to assign things to all fields in the way that you indicated.

It has the obvious drawback that fieldnames such as `'Pending Equity > T'` will get renamed to the much less pretty `'PendingEquity0x3ET'`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange that someone was able to create a struct like that.  Older version of Matlab, perhaps? Anyway, the only thing that comes to mind is the function `setfield`.  But chances are that it will give you the "Invalid field name" error too.

Comment: Yeah, as I commented in the answer above yours, these are ancient legacy systems I'm working with.  Here's the matlab versioning on startup: Version 7.5.0.338 (R2007b).  I did indeed get an "Invalid field name" error with setfield.
                                                                                  August 9, 2007

Comment: I edited my above comment, but no--setfield caused another "Invalid field name" error, as you predicted.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try.

Convert it to a valid data type: Use `fieldnames` and `struct2cell` to pop out the names and all the data elements from that cell. Then you can manually look up the field name in that list to get the index in to the cell array. You could write a little class that wraps both these up in fields and behaves just like a struct that allows arbitrary field names, which would be compatible with most code expecting structs. Or, if you can accept pass-by-reference behavior and different syntax, stick these in a `containers.Map`, which allows arbitrary strings as keys.

Or you could drop down to MEX and write your own `getfieldunsafe()` that lets you use bogus field names with these bogus structs. Try calling `mxGetField` and see if it'll work with the bogus field names. If not, have your MEX function manually look up the field name in the struct's field list, and then get the data using `mxGetFieldByNumber`. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/access-data.html.

Converting it to a valid object is probably best. If `struct2cell` and `fieldnames` give you trouble, you could drop down the MEX just for the conversion, to get the data out of the bogus struct one time.